# Tensorflow GPU for debian

Tags: tensorflow, debian, debian-stretch

Is it possible to install tensorflow GPU in debian? I am using Nvidia GTX 1070 ti and debian 9.3.0. I have tried several tutorials for Ubuntu but failed as debian doesn't have the same PPA repository supported by Ubuntu, also saw many saying that adding ubuntu's repository to debian is not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it's a hassle :)

I got Debian 9.3 with Openbox to work nicely with Tensorflow 1.6 and Cuda 9.0 + cuDNN 7.0.5.15 (eventually also Wavenet).

https://github.com/ella1011/debian_gpu_jungle

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using docker/[nvidia-docker](https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/). TensorFlow binary releases include docker images, so you could use those to avoid having to mess with your local environment.

Once you have docker/nvidia-docker installed, it would be something like this:

```
docker run -it --runtime=nvidia --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:1.6.0-gpu
```

And of course, you can use the `-v` flag to make directories in your host machine visible to the docker container.